# Find opaque types in the Informix database

Tags: informix, user-defined-data-types

I want to get a list of custom types (opaque types). Type information is stored in the sysxtdtypes system table, but opaque type is defined as basic (https://help.hcltechsw.com/hclinformix/1410/sqr/ids_sqr_084.html):

| extended_id | mode | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2056 | B | circle | 41 |

At the moment, I do not know by what rule extended_id is calculated.  [Judging by this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/289296/what-are-the-various-informix-column-data-types), type 41 can be anything (Unknown type (41, 24)). Is there any system table that stores user-defined types? Is there a way to distinguish a custom one from a basic one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the [`sysxtdtypes`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=tables-sysxtdtypes) table says that the `mode` column is a `CHAR(1)` containing:

> Code classifying the UDT:
>
> - B = Base (opaque) type
> - C = Collection type or unnamed ROW type
> - D = Distinct type
> - R = Named ROW type
> - S = Reserved for internal use
> - T = Reserved for internal use
> - ' ' (blank) = Built-in type

So, the entries in `sysxtdtypes` where `mode = 'B'` are the "user-defined" opaque types.  Note that some types are recorded in there when the database is created — including "blob", "clob", "json", "bson" and so on.  They have smaller values for `extended_id` — it looks as though types you create will have an ID value from 2048 upwards.  (At least, when I created a type for the Nth time, it came up with ID 2057.)

Comment: Yes, it looks like extended_id will be higher. However, I was unable to find out a certain rule. Could there be a situation in which the extended_id will be less. At the moment, I have not been able to understand the meaning and definition of the extended_id column

Comment: The extended ID is used by other tables to identify the type.  It's used in syscolumns for one; probably in a number of other tables too.  It's a bit like the table ID.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you tell me where I can find the answer to my question.
Is there a way to get the statement about the creation of the type? Example: 
create row type custom_type string(street VARCHAR(20), city VARCHAR(20);
getDDl(custom_type);